# How to exclude certain scripts in YAML?

Tags: yaml, auth0

in my YAML file, I have a bunch of codes, basically I want auth0 to be available in staging, but not available in production:

```
spring: 
    security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            registration:
              auth0:
                client-id: <ENV>
                client-secret: <ENV>
                scope:
                  - openid
                  - profile
                  - email
            provider:
              auth0:
                # trailing slash is important!
                issuer-uri: <ENV>
```

I want these to be conditional (maybe an IF statement?) that it will be available in staging, but not production, I can pass variables in this YAML file but I do not know how to do an if statement or make the code go away as none existing

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of code, nobody will be willing to take the time to help you. Include the code in your question so others can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer myself.

Need to run this on docker-compose in build pipeline:

```
yq -i 'del(.spring.security)' fooPath/foo.yml
```

using:

```
  yq:
    image: mikefarah/yq:4.35.1
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
    - .:/app
```

For windows users, please use (to test locally):

```
chocolatey install yq
```